# customize wooCommerce rest api response

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I when to create rest API for shopping site and i need to customize that API as my need  so can I customize wooCommerce rest API response like this

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Success.",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 794,
        "name": "Premium Quality",
        "slug": "premium-quality-19",
        "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-19/",
        "date_created": "2017-03-23T17:01:14",
        "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
        "date_modified": "2017-03-23T17:01:14",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
        "type": "simple",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": false,
        "catalog_visibility": "visible",
        "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
        "short_description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>\n",
        "sku": "",
        "price": "21.99",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "sale_price": ""
     },
  ]
}
```